# Simple link_to from root_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, root

I have a very simple view link_to problem no error message just a strange dot in url "http://0.0.0.0:3000/.Hire" not sure why the dot is there between the root url and Hire?

link_to:

```
<%= link_to page.name, root_url(page.name) %>
```

The routes are fine if I type manually: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/Hire`
I get taken to the right page but the link_to is just wrong.

I would be grateful for any help.

Many thanks

Dan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`root_url` isn't supposed to be given this kind of parameters. It's logic it's failing.

Run `rake_routes` in your console to get the proper names of your routes.

One ugly workaround to fit your needs would be:

```
<%= link_to page.name, root_url + page.name %>
```

One last question: why do you use `root_url` instead of `root_path`?

The former tend to uselessly pollute the views.

Comment: I just use root_url because it shorter, is there a reason why I should use root_path in it's stead?

Comment: compare the html created, it will answer by itself :)

Comment: Cheers mate you was a great help!!